# How do I start an NSTimer from my app delegate which calls my method in Viewcontroller.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nstimer, appdelegate

When my app closes I want it to call a void method in `viewController.m`

I tried this:

I have declared a `NSTimer`(alarmm) and the `void(alarm:)` in `viewController.h` and I have imported `viewController.h` in `Appdelegate.m`

```
AppDelegate.m:

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

    alarmm = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(alarm:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

but when it runs this comes

```
**2014-12-20 13:53:19.881 protect my phone[3292:959295] -[AppDelegate alarm:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170043810
2014-12-20 13:53:19.884 protect my phone[3292:959295] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate alarm:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170043810'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182e5659c 0x1935600e4 0x182e5d664 0x182e5a418 0x182d5eb6c 0x183d2ae18 0x182e0e8d8 0x182e0e588 0x182e0bfd4 0x182d390a4 0x18bee35a4 0x18766e3c0 0x10000a320 0x193bcea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**
```

Comment: Just FYI: Once your application enters background and is subsequently suspended, no timers will fire.

Answer (score 3):

As you said you declared `alarm` in some view controller but you try to call it on `AppDelegate`, where it is not defined.
Thus you get a crash with unrecognized selector on self.

Try exchanging the self in `NSTimer` creation to the view controllers reference ...

Answer (score 2):

As *dogsgod* already said, you set the target to `self`, which is the `AppDelegate`. So your scheduled timer will look for this method in the AppDelegate, but you implemented the alarm method in your view controller. You have to get a reference to your view controller and set this reference as target to your timer.

You could also register for the notification `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` in your view controller and create your timer in the notification callback, if you don't need anything important from your `AppDelegate`.

something list this in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)onAppDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTimer *alarmm = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(alarm:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```